# Apply filters before a visualization has been loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tableau-api

Hi I am trying to apply filters before a visualization has been loaded

```
angular.forEach(savedFilters, function(filterValues, filterName) {
     options[filterName] = filterValues;
});
viz = new tableauSoftware.Viz(angular.element('#chartVizId')[0], chartURL, options);
```

In the above code savedFitlers will vary, How can I handle if there is more data. Is there any limitation on size of the filters data and number of filters.How to handle this scenario.

Comment: what do you mean by `before visualization is loaded`?

Comment: Hey srikanth the first way for applying filters as mention in the following page https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_concepts_filtering.htm

Comment: Are you calling the tableau reports using javascript?

Comment: Yeah! using Tableau Javascript API